# what does "Depth" column mean(VM Trace Transaction)?

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, evm

What does "Depth" column  mean in VM Trace Transaction ?

How it is for opcodes?

for example here: https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/vmtrace?txhash=0xbb7323b02276aeed76b22fa50e2eefb76d5647560b8c15f23541ec5990d0e855

Comment: it is the stack, every call a new stack frame is created and put on the stack, works pretty much like any PC, grab a manual of assembly language and it is going to explain you everything. The only difference is that instructions are different

Answer (score 1):

It's the call depth. All opcodes inside the original transaction have depth of 1. If there is a message call to another contract, the depth is incremented by 1 for opcodes inside this message call. Recursively, if there is a message call inside that message call, the depth is 3 etc.